# Build path entry is missing in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I import an android project in eclipse. This project have a native library(adhoc.so). The library path is "libs\armeabi". It seem the library do not load properly and below line signed as error:

```
import adhoc.aodv.Node;
```

And in project properties some error occured. Please refer the attached image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5B30.jpg).

[image: error]

How can i fix these errors?

Comment: I solved my problem by marking the build reference that was unchecked at "Android" tab. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

go to search option in eclipse and go to file section and paste classpath and delete
adhoclibrary dependency path .
like that